# mysql partitioning by key internal hashing function

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We have a table partitioned by key (binary(16))

Is there any option to calculate which partition record will go outside of MySQL?
What is the hash function (not linear one)?

The reason is to sort the CSV files outside MySQL and insert them in parallel in right partitions with LOAD DATA INFILE and then index in parallel too.

I can't find the function in MySQL docs

Comment: There is practically no advantage in Hash partitioning.  Even if you devise a way to load partitions in parallel, I/O will probably limit the performance improvement to much less than 8x.  Please let us know how your experiment turns out.

Comment: Another significant factor is whether the data is arriving in `PRIMARY KEY` order.

Comment: That is may be right but after that comes indexing. We remove index before loading data. That way it goes faster. And then we index every partition. No io there. So all this is to make building the table faster. I understand that it won't improve the actual performance

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with Linear?  Are trying to LOAD in parallel?

How many indexes do you have?  If only that hash, sort the table, then load into a non-partitioned InnoDB with the PK already in place.  Meanwhile, make sure every column uses the smallest possible datatype.  How much RAM do you have?

If you are using MyISAM, consider `MERGE` - With that, you can load each partition-like table as in a separate thread.  When finished, construct the "merge" table that combines them.

What types of queries will you be using?  Single row lookups by the `BINARY(16)`?  Anything else might have big performance issues.

How much RAM?  We need to tune either `key_buffer_size` or `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Be aware of the limitations.  MyISAM defaults to a 7-byte data pointer and a 6-byte index pointer.  15TB would need only a 6-byte data pointer if the rows are `DYNAMIC` (byte pointer), or 5 bytes if they are `FIXED` (row number).  So that could be 1 or 2 bytes to be saved.  If anything is variable length, go with Dynamic; it would waste too much space (and probably not improve speed) to go fixed.  I don't know of the index pointer can be shrunk in your case.

You are in 5.7?  MySQL; 8.0 removes MyISAM.  Meanwhile, MariaDB still handles MyISAM.

Will you first split the data by "partition"?  Or send off `INSERTs` to different "partitions" one by one.  (This choice adds some more wrinkles and possibly optimizations.)

**Maybe...**

1. Sort the incoming data by the binary version of MD5().
2. Split into chunks based on the first 4 bits.  (Or do the split without sorting first)  Be sure to run `LOAD DATA` for one 4-bit value in only one thread.
3. Have `PARTITION BY RANGE` with 16 partitions:

   ```
    VALUES LESS THAN 0x1000000000000000
    VALUES LESS THAN 0x2000000000000000
    ...
    VALUES LESS THAN 0xF000000000000000
    VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
   ```

I don't know of a limit on the number of rows in a `LOAD DATA`, but I would worry about ACID locks having problems if you go over, say, 10K rows at a time.

This technique *may* even work for a non-partitioned table.

Comment: indexes are added after insertion of data to partitions. so if someone needs it: "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file.csv INTO TABLE t partition (p)".that way myisam lets you load data in parallel. and it goes much faster. and also you don't get the "merge" table limitations.

Comment: still i am not clear about function that mysql uses to split data in partition by key , when the key is binary(16), Bill said something take first three bytes and apply linear. but i am not sure what it means. need example. i need to be able to do it out of mysql server.

Comment: @YosefYudilevich - `BY RANGE` establishes partitions based on the "partition key" (numeric or string or binary) of a column.  Eg, `VALUE LESS THAN 100`, 200, etc.  `BY HASH` does a lame hashing (a simple modulo, in the case of numeric) of the partition key.

Comment: the question is about `BY KEY`. so if i have , say, two partitions `BY KEY` of binary(16),  how MySQL calculates to which of two it should add record.

Comment: I meant to say `BY KEY`

Comment: "by key" there is no stuff like "VALUES LESS THAN 0x1000000000000000" you just say by key, which key and number of partitions. then mysql uses some "internal function" as they call it, to route data to partitions. this function is what i need. when the key is binary(16). not hash and not range. by key

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-key.html#:~:text=Partitioning%20by%20key%20is%20similar,supplied%20by%20the%20MySQL%20server.

Comment: `Partitioning by key is similar to partitioning by hash, except that where hash partitioning employs a user-defined expression, the hashing function for key partitioning is supplied by the MySQL server. NDB Cluster uses MD5() for this purpose; for tables using other storage engines, the server employs its own internal hashing function which is based on the same algorithm as PASSWORD().`

Comment: @YosefYudilevich - Experiment with different layouts, 10K should be sufficient to provide useful timing data.  And be sure to note the "partitions" column in Explain.

Comment: the question is about the "internal hashing function". that is my big problem. not the layouts. i am just not good enough in C code to check in mysql source code how they implement this function for "partition by key". i need to understand the function implementation. may be i should change the question name or something

Comment: pointer to source code can also help though

Comment: @YosefYudilevich - In the 9 days we have been discussing the task, the brute force (non-parallel) approach could have been finished.  It may take another 9 days to finish writing the code for you.

Comment: I think I am about to figure out. Give me two days I might have an answer